# How to use FusedLocationProviderClient with appcompat-v7:25.1.1 and firebase-messaging:10.2.0?

Tags: java, android, dependencies

I have spent hours to use `FusedLocationProviderClient`. But the class is not found. It only works when I use `com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2`

[image]

When I change `com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.0` version to 11.0.2 or change the appcompat version I am getting dependency conflict errors. Also firebase auth errors.

Searched a lot on google but still no luck. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FusedLocationProviderClient` only works with `Play Services V 11.0.0` or later. Read [this](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/locationservices/) and [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/06/reduce-friction-with-new-location-apis.html) For this reason, in earlier versions, the class is not found. For you to use it, you need to update `google-play-services` dependencies. For the dependency conflict errors, follow the links in the gradle build errors list to install the required repositories.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did so after posting the question. It was working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to be of service. Can you mark the answer as accepted if you think it correctly answers the question?